# Key Filter returning unexpected results

Tags: managed-metadata, key-filter

I have a library which uses several columns of type Managed Metadata.

I have turned on both the tree navigation and key filters.  I am using several column-specific key filters, not the All Tags filter.

For a specific column, there are several levels of managed metadata terms.  For example:

```
Term 1
   Child 1
Term 2
   Child 2
   Child 3
         Child 4
```

If I used Child 4 as my term and apply the filter, I receive accurate results.  If I use Term 2, it only returns items tagged with Term 2, but it doesn't return items tagged with Term2:Child3 or Term 2: Child 3: Child 4

Using the tree navigation, if I click on the parent term, the results include all documents tagged with either the parent term or any child terms of that particular parent.

Is this a a bug or expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. The Metadata tree will return all items of the branch, the key filter will only return items with exactly that term, not its children.